# send event to specific kafka topic partition and read it by flume hive sink

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.10 and Flume 1.8. I am trying to get information on below (but could not get it). So can any body please help me.

1. Is there any way to send events to particular kafka topic partition
2. And if so, then can we read such events (coming to specific partition) with flume using hive sink

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your motive... I'm pretty sure you can create a kafka topic with a single partition if you wish to.

By doing this, you would know which partition and topic you were reading from. It is also possible to have multiple sources in flume, so if you wish for a single service to read from multiple topics but for each topic to only have a single partition, you can easily do this.

Apologies, I would have written this as a comment as it should really be a comment but I don't yet have that privilege in stackoverflow. Anyway, I hope this helps.